# Mac OS X Assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm

It seems from my initial reading there are two options for assembly on Mac OS X. 
 - C libraries 
 - BSD System Calls.
 - Something with Objective C

Is there an equivalent of the Win32 API on Mac OS X?

Apple uses Objective C heavily; how much does Objective C add on that changes using it in assembly?

Apple's CoreFoundation seems to be abandoned or not heavily used instead Apple choosing to go with Objective C and not regular C libraries.

Mac OS X seems to use the NASM assembler.

This is all coming from someone who has most of their experience in MASM and the Win32 API. I hope I am horribly informed here as it seems right now assembly on the Mac is bleak.

Answer (score 1):

As I view it, using Objective-C is only really necessary for writing GUI apps using Cocoa, though it can be used for other applications as there exists many mapping from Core Foundation functions to the Objective-C methods.

The CoreFoundation is certainly alive and kicking, especially as some parts of OSX don't use Objective-C, such as kernel extensions, which are exclusively C++ and the kernel itself is mostly C.

I would say that the Core Foundation libraries are the closest match to the Win32 API, but if you're looking to using Cocoa (GUI Widgets), then Objective-C is what you need to use, unless you want to opt for something like the [Qt framework](http://qt-project.org/).

As for ASM with Objective-C, Objective-C is a superset of the C language, so you can happily write [C functions with embedded ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425360/can-you-do-inline-assemble-in-objective-c), if that's what you want to do. Or just write pure assembly code, obeying the [OSX ABI function call guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html).